# Fiddler Script; default parameter value?

Tags: fiddler

Can't seem to find this on the docs anywhere, or on here.

I have a function;
`static function Foo(oSession: Session, item1: String, item2: String)`

Currently I call it like this;
`Foo(oSession, "bar", null);`

I would like to be able to omit the "null".

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# script is available in Fiddler now and luckily it compiles against .NET 4.0 so optional arguments are supported. So you have to switch to C#.

Comment: Is that done following [this guide](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/extend-fiddler/extendwithdotnet)? Is there a way I can just drop a C# script into fiddler without compiling?

Comment: No, in the current version of Fiddler you can choose between C# and Jscript for FiddlerScript language. It's in the options and once you choose C# you will get default script written in C# that you can modify. It will get compiled automatically at run time.